# How can I execute a shortcut in my path

Tags: windows, shortcuts, path

I have added a shortcut to an executable into a folder on my path, but I can not execute it as I would expect.

Is there a way to do this?  I have a bunch of small exe's I would like to keep organized in their installation folders.

I want execute these exes from and folder.  Thus I need them on my path.

I do not want to add yet another 10 directories to my path.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: "I can not execute it as I would expect." How are you trying to execute it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this would to be [create Symbolic Links](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc753194%28v=ws.11%29) to the files (programs) in question.
Suppose you have a single folder (`C:\bin`) that you add to your system path. Then in that folder
you can create Symbolic Links to executables that you want to have quickly accessible.

Now, further suppose that there are several applications that you want to have quick access to, either from the
command line or from the Windows/Run box. For example, let's say that your program list includes:

```
  "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
  "C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe"
  "C:\Program Files\iTunes\iTunes.exe"
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

To create the symbolic links for the above, you might:

```
  mkdir c:\bin
  cd /d c:\bin

  mklink 7z.exe "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
  mklink ahk.exe "C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe"
  mklink iTunes.exe "C:\Program Files\iTunes\iTunes.exe"
  mklink devenv.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
  mklink npp.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

You'll notice that I've “renamed” `AutoHotKey.exe` to `ahk.exe` and `Notepad++.exe` to `npp.exe` in these examples, thus providing shorthand names for them.

As with many things in Windows, there are other perfectly valid ways to achieve the same thing. One would be create [Windows
Command Line Aliases](https://web.archive.org/web/20150112095213/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/robdelacruz/archive/2004/08/22/218499.aspx). Another would be to use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). Still another would be to create Windows Shortcuts
and add the `.lnk` extension to the `PATHEXT` environment variable as [@Ben N](https://superuser.com/users/380318/ben-n) describes in his answer. Or, you could even use [doskey.exe](https://web.archive.org/web/20171228183552/http://www.microsoft.com:80/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/doskey.mspx?mfr=true) to get there, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt) post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Personally, I *primarily* use aliases because I tend to use the Windows Command Line a lot. I do also use AutoHotKey, however, when the situation calls for it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to update the `PATHEXT` system environment variable. That variable lists the file types that are considered executable for the purposes of path-searching. Append `;.LNK` to that variable's value, thereby making shortcuts (`.lnk`) something that will be searched for on your `PATH`. Note that you may need to restart running command prompts for the change to take effect.

Comment: +1 for the info that windows shortcuts are actually .lnk files.